# What's the different between index and update document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

As we know when we update an existed document the Elasticsearch engine will reindex the document and mark the previous document deleted. But for the restful API, it's same. So I guess the ElasticSearch will analysis the document whether exist by the unique document ID and then update or index.

So my question is, we don't need to care the index or update functionality, because both restful API and Java Client are `PUT` the same endpoint, Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The most difference for `PUT` and `POST` document in **Elasticsearch**:

1. `POST` will create a new document with **a new unique ID**.
2. `PUT` will update the current document without **change ID**.

so if your **ID** is important to you like for **some context**, you should use **PUT** to update a document to **keep this ID**.

Comment: I knew what you said. I mean what's the difference between `PUT` a document with ID and without ID. Even in Java Client there is a way to set an ID when index the document first time.